# Getting the value of matching columns in WPS spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, wps

I have two spreadsheets where I maintain Item SubCategory and Item details.

[image: exmple data]

What I want is to add SubCategoryId to the Item table if the CategoryId and the SubCategoryName in the Item table match the CategoryId and the SubCategoryName in SubCategory Table. Hope it makes sense. How do I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` standard or `INDEX/MATCH` array formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A11=$C$4:$C$6)*(D11=$B$4:$B$6)*($A$4:$A$6))
```

or

```
{=INDEX($A$4:$A$6;MATCH(1;(A11=$C$4:$C$6)*(D11=$B$4:$B$6);0);0)}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]